# Image row sizing

Tags: html, css

I'm struggling to get a row containing three images to be sized correctly. The three images are equally sized (270px x 270px) and share a common background image (a shadow) which is sized 310px x 310px and is rendered when the mouse is hovered over any of the three images. jsFiddle here: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cvh2013/5WsMr/)

I have tried inserting style="height:310px;" into the `td` tag, the `tr` tag and into the `.center` CSS, neither of which sizes the row correctly - the top and botom of the background shadow image are cut off.

Does anyone have a pointer for me? Thank you.

CSS:

```
.center {
text-align: center;
}

#images:hover {
background-image: url(http://ubuntuone.com/1SRrDB8i8cBtpm3Smxaz5r);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position:center;     
}
```

HTML:

```
<table style="width: 100%">
    <tr>
            <td class="center">
                <div id="images">
                <object class="images" type="image/svg+xml"
                    data="http://ubuntuone.com/5b5ZUS86nHAffWiOirDwFr">
                    <img src="http://ubuntuone.com/12qOaTGCZYzQtqFJpaGbPV" alt="" />
                </object>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="center">
                <div id="images">
                <object type="image/svg+xml"
                    data="http://ubuntuone.com/7Ur09JXlGVvF2GhXFbLXlx">
                    <img src="http://ubuntuone.com/54AaqhQUU8npACF2vXzKFp" alt="" />
                </object>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="center">
                <div id="images">
                <object type="image/svg+xml"
                    data="http://ubuntuone.com/6tkHm9c2r1eH9PMB9Nr3Ux">
                    <img src="http://ubuntuone.com/4CXw05d1dsSf9VhAIPNZf6" alt="" />
                </object>
                </div>
            </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just give proper padding to your divs containing images

update your `#images` css to this:

```
#images
{
    padding:20px;
}
#images:hover {
    background-image: url(http://ubuntuone.com/1SRrDB8i8cBtpm3Smxaz5r);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:center;     
    padding:20px;
}
```

see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manishmishra256/5WsMr/1/)

Answer (score 3):

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/5WsMr/4/)

Your images do not have enough space around them to show shadow properly.
You can just add more space by adding some padding in your image `div`

```
#images{
    padding:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried styling a

```
    table td.center {
        attributes
    }
```

in CSS

Comment: Thank you Four_lo, I tried this but was unable to get it right. I'm an amateur at this, so probably my error ...

Comment: @ClivevanHilten CSS seems to be simple except for when things go wrong then it comes up with all sorts of new rules

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

`#images{
    padding:15px;
}`

Works perfect!